# Double simpler for loop vs one complex

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop, optimization

Maybe this is a stupid question, but say I've got like two functions, void F1(int x) and void F2(int x), and I want to execute them in each iteration of a for loop. How much would it difer (performance-wise) if I did one big for loop, like this:

```
`
for(int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++)
{
    F1(i);
    F2(i);
}
`
```

compared to doing two separate loops, one in which I call F1, one in which I call F2:

```
`
for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++)
    F1(i);
for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++)
    F2(i);
`
```

While writing this, it occured to me that the first way is probably faster because there are only aproximately 100 increments and 100 comparisons, while in the second case, we'll get 200 of each.

Say my loop only has to run for 200 iterations. Would the two-for loops approach be pretty much the same in terms of performance, considering, say, CPUs from 2007 and after:)?

Comment: Simplest thing: write a test that measures the time taken for both cases

Comment: If there is any performance difference, it's likely to be dominated by cache locality. The answer will likely depend entirely on the actual use case. The only solution is to try both in your actual application and measure.

Comment: Keep in mind, the two examples differ in behavior. The first will interweave calls to `F1` and `F2` while the second will preform all the calls to `F1` and then all the calls to `F2`. Use whichever is correct and easier to read and understand. Only if you later measure a bottleneck in that code should you worry about performance.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Additionally, since this is likely to be a cache issue, the performance characteristics of this code may vary considerably from one type of CPU to another. An i5 might handle this in a way totally different from a Xeon used in production. There's no easy right answer here because as you suggest, the answer begins with "It depends..."

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what `F1` and `F2` do.

It could not matter at all or you can experience dramatic slow down by having both functions called one after the other.

As an example of the latter case consider `F1` and `F2` accessing two different arrays. At each run of `F1` and `F2` they read enough data to cause the whole cache to be overwritten. That would probably cause a good slow down.

But is always better not to speculate and measure and benchmark your code instead. If performance is equivalent for both versions go for the most readable.

Comment: The opposite is also possible: if `F1` and `F2` access similar data for a given `i`, the first case will likely be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you pointed out the amount of operations differ. **However**, if you go with the second solution you can use multiple threads and achieve the same or better performance. Also, **consider readability, testability, expandability, encapsulation**, usually those factors are more important than any small performance gain you might get. And also, the compiler is usually very great at making your code run more effectively, so my advice is focus on your readability more than your performance in most cases.